# Rshiny summary statistics for specific column

Tags: r, dashboard, shinydashboard, rshiny

I'm having an error while parsing the data, the program should work when the user chose the variable and click calculate and it will show the min,median,max,1st quartile and 3rd quartile. As for now it shows all the variables instead of one.

```
observeEvent(newdata_reactive$newdata(),{
choices <- c(not_sel,names(newdata_reactive$newdata()))
updateSelectInput(inputId = "var_1", choices = choices)
})

var_1 <- eventReactive(input$btn,input$var_1)


output$total <-renderText({
    calculate()
    dataset <- newdata_reactive$newdata()
    summary(dataset)
  })
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rGQ44.png)

Comment: Please provide complete `server` and `ui` code relevant to your question, also share the data to verify the answer. You can also use inbuilt datasets like `mtcars`, `iris`.

Answer (score 1):

Change the `summary(dataset)` line to:

```
summary(dataset[,which(colnames(dataset)==input$var_1)])
```

This will summarize only the one column that is selected from dataset in input$var_1.